# Make a div clickable and copyable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As stated in the question, I have a div that I want to make clickable and copy-able?

to make the div copy-able, I simply do as following

```
<a href="/example.com">
  <div class="div">i contain some text</div>
</a>
```

But when trying to copy the text in that are inside of the div, the link gets clicked. What I want to do is that when clicking on the div, it should go to the url and that works. But I want also to make it possible to copy the text that is inside of the clickable div.

I prefer to fix the problem with html & css but even javascript is acceptable as last last resort.

Comment: I don't understand what should happen, when clicking on the div should it behave like a link(take you to another url) or not?

Comment: link gets linked ??

Comment: Also, do you just want the text copied, or the entire div, which is a block element?

Comment: Your question is unclear, given the ambiguities and your lack of any response to those asking for further information. Based on your inattentiveness - within even the first seven minutes as I write - I'm voting to close as "*unclear what you're asking*." Please, after asking a question be prepared to invest some time and effort into clarifying the question and responding to questions from those who would like to try and help you. The more input you provide the more likely you are to receive a useful answer. Take the "*[tour]*," learn "*[ask]*" and read about "*[mcve]*".

Comment: when clicking on the div, it should go to the url and that works. but i want also to make it possible to copy the text that is inside of the clickable div.

Comment: @DavidThomas  lack of any response? my inattentiveness ? i need some minutes to formulate a better description to my problem

Comment: @Joel_Blum: when clicking on the div, it should go to the url and that works. But I want also to make it possible to copy the text that is inside of the clickable div.

Comment: @MajorProductionsLLC i want only to copy the text inside the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires javascript, and we need 3 events to identify if the user is copying the text. Check out the snippet below, Let me know if it helps.

```js
class Box {
  constructor(target) {
    this.isUserCoping = false;
    this.isMouseClicked = false;
    this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this)
    this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this)
    this.handleMouseUp = this.handleMouseUp.bind(this)
    
    let $target = document.querySelector(target);
    $target.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleMouseDown), 
    $target.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove), 
    $target.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUp);
  }

  handleMouseDown() {
    this.isMouseClicked = true;
  }
  
  handleMouseMove() {
    this.isMouseClicked && (this.isUserCoping = true);
    this.isMouseClicked = false;
  }

  handleMouseUp(e) {
    !this.isUserCoping && this.navigate(e.target.dataset.href)
    console.log(this.isUserCoping);
    this.isUserCoping = false;
    console.log(this.isUserCoping);
  }
  
  navigate(href) {
    window.location.href = href;
  }
}

new Box('.js-div');
```

```html
  <div class="js-div" data-href='https://www.google.com'>i contain some text</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

add following:

```
.div{
  display:inline-block
}
```

Comment: In what way do you believe that this would address the OP's problem? It doesn't - in any way that I can see, or anticipate - but if you explained your answer you might convince me (and the other downvoter(s)) that you're right. Also, that way the OP , future visitors and I myself, might learn something from your answer, making it a far better answer and far more likely to earn you some reputation points (insofar as you value those).

Comment: I thought he has a condition where there is a <div> tag inside <a> tag. since <div> is a block element so it acquire entire row, so one finds difficulty to copy the text. making div inline-block helps